# Update historical results from wrong recurrent query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, analytics

Hi I am wondering how to go about the following situation: I have a recurrent query (PostgreSQL DB V12 instance) which runs and inserts data into a table for customer volume with 6 different metrics on a daily basis, creating a snapshot of the dataset over time:

```
26/03/2021| Active Linked Customers | 10
26/03/2021| Customers where all accounts have positive consent | 20
26/03/2021| Customer with accounts with a mixture of positive consent and > 90 days | 30
26/03/2021| Customers who have all accounts > 30 days | 40
26/03/2021| Customers who have ever connected >=1 account | 50
26/03/2021| Customer record created but customer never connected an account | 5
25/03/2021| Active Linked Customers | 7
25/03/2021| Customers where all accounts have positive consent | 9
25/03/2021| Customer with accounts with a mixture of positive consent and > 90 days | 30
25/03/2021| Customers who have all accounts > 30 days| 40
25/03/2021| Customers who have ever connected >=1 account | 50
25/03/2021| Customer record created but customer never connected an account | 4
...
```

I have now realised that I need to tweak / fix a where clause of my query that has been generating all results for a couple of months now. This fix is to exclude accounts that have been deleted already from the system, I just need to add the following clause:

```
where deleted_date is not NULL
```

The query has been built on 6 different CTEs that feeds the table above on a daily basis. The fix is for future results is straightforward, but how to "fix" the historical data and exclude deleted accounts from the results? Is there a way to reverse engineer the results and "go back in time" to tweak the query and rerun for the last couple of months? Or even some clever data analysis to get around this? Any ideas / suggestions?

Comment: More specific sample data and the expected result is needed. You may be able to handle it via UPDATE, if all the information required is available in the table. Otherwise the approach will vary entirely on your environment.

Comment: Added more information to the issue - please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Since you don't have the delete_date in your final table I think the only thing you can do is load an intermediate table from your source application with all the keys + delete dates and use that to patch your history.